# Component not showing as an option to add to a placeholder?

Tags: experience-editor, placeholders, dynamic-placeholder

All my other components display as options to add when I click on my main placeholder in Experience Editor.

However one component is not shown in the list and I can't see why. I've added it to the main placeholder placeholder settings in: /sitecore/layout/Placeholder Settings

Am I missing something here?

I'm running Sitecore 8.1 update 2.

Comment: Is there a typo in the question? In the second sentence, should it read "however, one component is NOT shown in the list and I can't see why"

Answer (score 14, accepted):

Ensure that the component (either the sublayout, view rendering item or the controller rendering item) has it's "editable" checkbox checked.

[image]